# Why can't I show my data in ContentView despite having a model for it?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Why can't I show my data in `ContentView` despite already having a ViewModel for it?
This is my ViewModel, called `SessionAuth`:

```swift
class SessionAuth: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: User?
    @Published var isLoggedIn = false
    @Published var showError = false
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var userId: String?
    
    init() {
        checkLoginStatus()
    }

func fetchUser() {
        if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            db.collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { (document, error) in
                if let document = document, document.exists {
                    if let user = try? document.data(as: User.self) {
                        self.user = user
                        print("data tersedia")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("document does not exist")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my `ContentView`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sessionAuth: SessionAuth
    
    var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      Text("Putut Yusri Bahtiar \(sessionAuth.user?.name ?? "-")")
             .font(.headline)
             .foregroundColor(.primary)
             .padding(.leading)
                            
     HStack {
       Image(systemName: "creditcard")
         .foregroundColor(.white)
                                
       Text("IDR 2000")
         .foregroundColor(.white)
      }
      .padding(.leading)
    }
}
```

I want to read all data from Firebase Firestore with the `User` model to ContentView, but it's not showing the data.

Comment: You don't call `fetchUser()` anywhere, so you will not get the user info.
Add this: `.onAppear { sessionAuth.fetchUser() }` to your `ContentView` `VStack`.

Comment: i already add onAppear { sessionAuth.fetchUser() } to ContentView on Vstack its not update

Comment: ok, in `fetchUser()`  try using `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.user = user }` and of course also use `.onAppear { sessionAuth.fetchUser() }`

Comment: `if let user = try? document.data(as: User.self) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.user = user
                        }`

ok im already add this on my fetchUser() but its not show.

Comment: could you use `print("user: \(user)")` inside the `DispatchQueue.main.async...`, instead of `print("data tersedia")` and show us what it prints.

Comment: after i successfully logged in, its not show the `print("user: \(user)")`.

Comment: well now you know why you cannot show any data, it is because you don't have any data to show. Since the `login` is a asynchronous function, I suspect you are trying to get to the data `before` you are really logged in. In `fetchUser()` add
    
    `if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {...} else { print("no current user, not logged in") }`

Comment: well im already add that in fetchUser()

Comment: i want get data after i logged in

Comment: did you get the message "no current user, not logged in"

Comment: no i didnt get message that after i logged.

Comment: do you get the message "document does not exist"

Comment: no i dont get that message

Comment: If you don't get any of these prints:
no `print("user: \(user)")` no 
`print("document does not exist")` and no 
`print("no current user, not logged in")` 
 it means in `fetchUser()`, `try? document.data(as: User.self)` is `nil`.  
Use a `do/try/catch` and `print(error)` in `catch` to debug the code.

Or use if let user = try? document.data(as: User.self) {....} `else { print("no user data") }`

Comment: `if let user = try? document.data(as: User.self) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.user = user
                        }
                        print("user: \(user)")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("document does not exist")
                }` 

i already have that. you can check full that script on this : https://github.com/pututyb/Moovie/blob/main/Moovie/ViewModel/SessionAuth.swift

Comment: as I said, use `let user = try? document.data(as: User.self) {....} else { print("no user data") }`. You don't have that, and this is the only other way the code can run.

Comment: Debug your code, there are a lot of `if` statements which exit silently if the condition is `false`. And why do you check `currentUser` multiple times? And rather than optional `User` and two other boolean properties consider an `enum` with associated values and cases `isLoggedIn(User)`, `isNotLoggedIn`, `failure(Error)`. The benefit is only one **non-optional** `@Published`  property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since this is too much for the comment, try this code, and show what it prints.

```
func fetchUser() {
    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        db.collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                do {
                    let user = try document.data(as: User.self)
                    print("user: \(user)")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.user = user
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("error: \(error)")
                }
            } else {
                print("document does not exist")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("no user uid, not logged in")
    }
}
```